# Execute OpenCL code on the CPU

Tags: linux, cpu, gpu, gpgpu, opencl

I want to execute [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) code on a PC which doesn't have a graphics card, nor any other hardware component which is able to execute OpenCL. Is it possible compile my OpenCL code in a way that it can be executed on the CPU in Linux? Or is it possible to simulate a GPU environment on the CPU?

Note: It's about testing whether the code works as expected, not about performance.

Comment: Take a look at pocl: http://pocl.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This](http://www.khronos.org/message_boards/showthread.php/8600-Running-openCL-on-CPU) looks like what you need, although you probably need to recompile, and the SDK linked from there appears specific to Intel CPUs; [this](http://developer.amd.com/resources/heterogeneous-computing/opencl-zone/getting-started-with-opencl/) link to AMD's documentation appears to describe the equivalent for AMD CPUs.

Comment: I could have come to this myself... The solution was simply to change `CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU` to `CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU` as described in the first link...

Comment: Well, if I saved you some time, I'd say that's a win for both of us. Glad to be of help!

Comment: Definitely saved me some time, thanks for the help :)

Comment: You may need to use "device fission" to fully use n-1 cores instead of not-fully using n cores.